# Where do the Game of Thrones graphic novels stand in the chronological reading order?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire, comics, canon, chronological-order

Do the 4 volumes of the graphic novels *The Game of Thrones* fall anywhere chronologically or are they more standalone?

Where do they stand in any suggested reading order, chronological or otherwise?

I am a stickler for reading fantasy series chronologically. I usually follow the [All timelines guide](https://www.alltimelines.com/category/beginners-guide/) for my chronological fantasy reading mixing up novels, short stories, graphic novels, novellas etc. just to keep with the chronology.

But *Game of Thrones* is not part of their index, so any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

### They Re-tell the stories of ASoIaF

If I understand you correctly, you seem to be asking where they fall in the chronology in-universe wise. Where the histories come before the main series. A Storm of Swords comes after A Game of Thrones and The Winds of Winter is the latest.

In that case they move along parallel to the main series. They are a re-telling of the main series in a comic book format. The aim was to have about 1 page of text for 1 page of comic.

> We wound up at an outline of twenty-four issues at twenty-nine pages each. Â All told, that gives us about a page of art for every page of text in the original book.
> <sub>[From an interview by CBR online with one of the creators: Daniel Abraham](http://www.cbr.com/abraham-plays-a-game-of-thrones/)</sub>

Although they've talked to GRRM, he himself is writing none of the comics or stories and just helping them with plot points and such.

> That said, it’s very clear that George isn’t writing the comic book. He’s put a great deal of faith and trust in me on the actually working out of the scripts. Â And God forbid I get in the way of his writing “The Winds of Winter.”
> <sub>[ibid.](http://www.cbr.com/abraham-plays-a-game-of-thrones/)</sub>

As for their canonicity. According to GRRM only the things he published in his books (ASOIAF and D&E) are canon, and although they're officially licensed. They are as non-canon as the TV-show. A complete post on what is canon can be [found here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/175057/how-is-canon-determined-for-the-works-set-in-the-world-of-asoiaf)

> Only the novels (and the Dunk & Egg novellas) are canon.
>
> The videogames, the board games, the card games, the comic book, even the television shows... all great in their own right, I hope, but still secondary. The books are canon. Nothing else.

Comment: I don't think it's even true that the things GRRM writes are necessarily canon. I doubt he would consider the episodes of _Game of Thrones_ that he scripted to be canonical for _A Song of Ice and Fire_.

Comment: By the things he writes (as outlined in the quote) I mean the ASOIAF series and the D&E novellas is what he deems are canon. Edited to be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

"A Game of Thrones the graphic novel" is just the adaptation of the first book in the A Song of Ice and Fire series also titled "A Game of Thrones". So it would fall at the same place as the original story.

I should also note that there are 2 other graphic novels of "The Hedge Knight" and "The Sworn Sword", two of the novellas from the "Tales of Dunk and Egg" prequel series, and are the same being comic adaptation of the standard books by George RR Martin.